# Customizer partial refresh issue with custom option

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a custom option I've added to customizer to control the layout and allow the option to change the number of grids. Everything works properly when the option is saved and published but'm having an issue getting the live refresh part to work in customizer. :(

This is the custom option I have set up:

```
$wp_customize->add_section(
    'theme_options', array(
        'title'       => esc_html__( 'Theme Options ', 'testtheme' ),
        'priority'    => 250,
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'dynamicgrid', array(
        'default'     => 'standard-layout',
        'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'testtheme_sanitize_grid_options',
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    'dynamicgrid', array(
        'settings'    => 'dynamicgrid',
        'label'       => esc_html__( 'Choose A Post Layout','testtheme' ),
        'section'     => 'theme_options',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'choices'     => array(
            'standard-layout'       => esc_html__( 'Standard Layout','testtheme' ),
            'two-grid-layout'       => esc_html__( 'Two Column Grid','testtheme' ),
            'three-grid-layout'     => esc_html__( 'Three Column Grid','testtheme' ),
            'four-grid-layout'      => esc_html__( 'Four Column Grid','testtheme' ),
        ),
    )
);
```

To use the refresh I call

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'dynamicgrid' )->transport       = 'postMessage';

$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial(
    'dynamicgrid', array(
        'selector'          => '.posts-container',
        'settings'          => 'dynamicgrid',
        'render_callback'   => 'testtheme_customize_partial_grid_classes',
    )
);
```

and my render_callback is:

`function testtheme_customize_partial_grid_classes( $testtheme_grid_layout ) {
    $grid_layout = get_option( 'dynamicgrid' );
    echo $grid_layout;
}`

What happens when I change the option in customizer is, it does add a new class to the .posts-container but the actual preview does not update.

My grid does have masonry applied as well but I don't think thats affecting anything. If it helps, this is in my customizer.js:

```
wp.customize(
    'dynamicgrid', function( value ) {
        value.bind(
            function( to ) {
                if ( 'standard-layout' === to ) {
                    $( '.posts-container' ).addClass( 'standard-layout' ).removeClass( 'two-grid-layout three-grid-layout four-grid-layout' );
                } else if ( 'two-grid-layout' === to ) {
                    $( '.posts-container' ).addClass( 'two-grid-layout' ).removeClass( 'standard-layout three-grid-layout four-grid-layout' );
                } else if ( 'three-grid-layout' === to ) {
                    $( '.posts-container' ).addClass( 'three-grid-layout' ).removeClass( 'standard-layout two-grid-layout four-grid-layout' );
                } else {
                    $( '.posts-container' ).addClass( 'four-grid-layout' ).removeClass( 'standard-layout two-grid-layout three-grid-layout' );
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

And I have this in my global.js file to make sure masonry loads properly:

```
(function($) {
// Taken almost entirely from Baskerville. NEed to double check this...
// posts block for Masonry.
var $blocks = $( '.masonry-enabled' );

$( window ).load(
    function() {
            /**
             * Initial Masonry setup.
             */

            // Determine text direction.
            var ltr = true;
        if ( $( 'html' ).attr( 'dir' ) == 'rtl' ) {
            ltr = false;
        }

            // fire up Masonry!
            $blocks.imagesLoaded(
                function() {
                    $blocks.masonry(
                        {
                            columnWidth: 1,
                            itemSelector: '.grid-post',
                            transitionDuration: 0,
                            isOriginLeft: ltr,
                        }
                    ).masonry( 'layout' );

                    var masonryChild = $blocks.find( '.grid-post' );

                    // Animating JS based off Huntt theme.
                    masonryChild.each(
                        function( i ) {
                            // Show content.
                            setTimeout(
                                function() {
                                    masonryChild.eq( i ).addClass( 'post-loaded fade-in' );
                                }, 100 * ( i + 1 )
                            );
                        }
                    );

                    $( '#spinner' ).fadeOut(
                        250, function() {
                            $( this ).remove();
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
    }
);

} )( jQuery );
```

I know I've missed something but I'm not really sure. any help is appreciated :)

*** Update ***

I'm still having some issues with this... Needing to create a custom selective refresh Partial type makes total sense. So I added the javascript in the this thread: [Add or remove HTML class with selective refresh?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272991/add-or-remove-html-class-with-selective-refresh/273205#273205) my customizer.js file which is being enqueued.

I Changed `partialConstructor.body_class` to `partialConstructor.grid_class`, updated the customizer.php file to also include the type like this:

```
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial(
    'dynamicgrid', array(
        'selector'          => '.posts-container',
        'type'              => 'grid_class',
        'settings'          => 'dynamicgrid',
        'render_callback'   => 'testtheme_customize_partial_grid_classes',
    )
);
```

and then back in my js file, I changed `body = $( '.posts-container' );` so that this updates classes on the .posts-container div instead of the body tag as the example shows.

This seems to make sense to me but now I get an error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'partialConstructor' of undefined
at VM3068 customizer.js?ver=4.8.3:12
at VM3068 customizer.js?ver=4.8.3:91
```

Which means I've missed something or put it in the wrong place?

This is my entire customzier.js file if it helps?

```
/**
 * File customizer.js.
 *
 * Theme Customizer enhancements for a better user experience.
 * Contains handlers to make Theme Customizer preview reload changes asynchronously.
 *
 * @package Testtheme
 */

( function( $ ) {

wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.partialConstructor.grid_class = wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.Partial.extend({

    /**
     * Class name choices.
     *
     * This is populated in PHP via `wp_add_inline_script()`.
     *
     * @type {Array}
     */
    choices: [],

    /**
     * Refresh partial.
     *
     * Override refresh behavior to bypass partial refresh request in favor of direct DOM manipulation.
     *
     * @returns {jQuery.Promise} Resolved promise.
     */
    refresh: function() {
        var partial = this, setting, body, deferred, className;

        setting = wp.customize( partial.params.primarySetting );
        className = setting.get();
        body = $( '.posts-container' );
        body.removeClass( partial.choices.join( ' ' ) );
        body.addClass( className );

        // Do good diligence and return an expected value from the function.
        deferred = new $.Deferred();
        deferred.resolveWith( partial, _.map( partial.placements(), function() {
            return '';
        } ) );
        return deferred.promise();
    }
});

// Site title and description.
wp.customize(
    'blogname', function( value ) {
        value.bind(
            function( to ) {
                $( '.site-title span' ).text( to );
            }
        );
    }
);

wp.customize(
    'blogdescription', function( value ) {
        value.bind(
            function( to ) {
                $( '.site-description' ).text( to );
            }
        );
    }
);

// Grid Settings.
wp.customize(
    'dynamicgrid', function( value ) {
        value.bind(
            function( to ) {
                if ( 'standard-layout' === to ) {
                    $( '.posts-container' ).addClass( 'standard-layout' ).removeClass( 'two-grid-layout three-grid-layout four-grid-layout' );
                } else if ( 'two-grid-layout' === to ) {
                    $( '.posts-container' ).addClass( 'two-grid-layout' ).removeClass( 'standard-layout three-grid-layout four-grid-layout' );
                } else if ( 'three-grid-layout' === to ) {
                    $( '.posts-container' ).addClass( 'three-grid-layout' ).removeClass( 'standard-layout two-grid-layout four-grid-layout' );
                } else {
                    $( '.posts-container' ).addClass( 'four-grid-layout' ).removeClass( 'standard-layout two-grid-layout three-grid-layout' );
                }
            }
        );
    }
);




} )( jQuery );
```

*** UPDATE NUMBER TWO ***

This is my current javascript class with added masonry

```
wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.partialConstructor.grid_class = 
wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.Partial.extend({

    /**
     * Class name choices.
     *
     * This is populated in PHP via `wp_add_inline_script()`.
     *
     * @type {Array}
     */
    choices: [],

    /**
     * Refresh partial.
     *
     * Override refresh behavior to bypass partial refresh request in favor of direct DOM manipulation.
     *
     * @returns {jQuery.Promise} Resolved promise.
     */
    refresh: function() {
        var partial = this, setting, body, deferred, className;

        setting = wp.customize( partial.params.primarySetting );
        className = setting.get();
        body = $( '.posts-container' );
        if ( 'standard-layout' === className ) {
            body.removeClass( 'masonry-enabled' );
        } else {
            body.addClass( 'masonry-enabled' );
        }
        body.removeClass( partial.choices.join( ' ' ) );
        body.addClass( className );
        body.masonry( 'reloadItems' );
        body.masonry( 'layout' );

        // Do good diligence and return an expected value from the function.
        deferred = new $.Deferred();
        deferred.resolveWith( partial, _.map( partial.placements(), function() {
            return '';
        } ) );
        return deferred.promise();
    }


});
```

Comment: How is `get_option( 'dynamicgrid' )` normally rendered out into the template on the frontend, outside the context of the customizer? Is it just adding classes to a `.posts-container` element?

Comment: If so, you may want to refer to my answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/273205/8521

Comment: hey @WestonRuter, yes, its literally just adding a class to the .posts-container. I knew I must have been missing something, thanks :)

Comment: hey @WestonRuter, I've updated my post above to include the js you suggested. I thought I'd done everything correctly but now I get an error in console which makes me think I must have put the .js in the wrong place or missed something simple? :(

Comment: You have to enqueue the JS with a dependency on `customize-selective-refresh`. Remember to only enqueue this JS if in the Customizer preview. Inside a `wp_enqueue_scripts` callback you can check `is_customize_preview()`.

Comment: Thanks @WestonRuter that works! Knew I'd missed something :)
All that I need to do now is get masonry to work again in the live refresh as well. I could see masonry working correctly at one stage, it would add my class and live refresh but then the customizer would refresh and revert it to what had been saved and published. So I'm guessing I have to add something else to the Javascript class that overrides the refresh method to also refresh/re initialise masonry? No idea what though... (sorry for continually questioning you, I can't find any documentation/articles about this bit)

Comment: Inside your custom Partial's `refresh` method you can add the Masonry call after you change the class. Refer to Twenty Thirteen: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/a4f27c25bc86483491959ccbb364cfccff4d6f8d/src/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/js/functions.js#L159-L160

Comment: You shouldn't need the secondary JS for Grid Settings in your snippet if you have the selective refresh partial as well. The partial then handles it.

Comment: I'm sooooo close now. I'm certain ;) 
I've added `body.masonry( 'reloadItems' ); body.masonry( 'layout' );` to the javascript class and when I inspect I can see that masonry is firing inside customizer but its still not quite right. It does recalculate but not correctly...
I've updated the original post again with the updated class. I also added a check for when standard-layout is applied as thats one column so no need for masonry. Can you direct any further to get this working? Thanks again for all your help, this is definitely a learning curve for me :)

Comment: If you create a standalone example plugin that can be used to demonstrate the issue that would be best. Putting it up on a Gist would allow for collaboration.

Comment: Hey @westonruter, Thanks for the suggestion. I've created a small plugin and put it in a Gist. Hopefully my ramblings seem to make a little more sense :)
[Gist link here](https://gist.github.com/kirstyburgoine/a1c5e9f92974a40c0840a6028828b987)